# Java get Array from parsed html table

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jsoup

I want to get the data from a table in an Array from Java

I already parsed the data from the table and stored it in a String. But each row of the is a new line in my String. I want to get all lines in one Array.

My String x prints out every price in a new line:

```
$25,913,000
$40,388,000
$48,995,000
$3,956,000
$12,087,000
$131,339,000
$170,799,000
$41,304,000
$0
$0
$22,283,000
$0
$365,725,000
$55,888,000
$20,748,000
$40,230,000
$116,866,000
$93,735,000
$45,180,000
$2,797,000
$0
$0
$258,578,000
$40,201,000
$0
$70,400,000
$0
($3,454,000)
$107,147,000
$365,725,000
```

That´s my code

```
try {

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.connect(url_balance_year).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
        Elements trs = doc.select("tr");

        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element tr : trs) {

            Elements tds = tr.select(".td_genTable");

            if (tds.size() == 0) continue;

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element td = tds.first().siblingElements().first();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element td1 = tds.first().nextElementSibling();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element td2 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element td3 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element td4 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

           String x = td1.ownText();

           System.out.println(x);

           //Here I want to all the prices from String x in one Array               

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

How can I get all the prices from String x in one Array??

Comment: Yes but that doesn´t solute my problem

Comment: Maybe, but if somebody read this he should know that it is not good

Answer (score 0):

instead of just printing strings with `System.out.println(x);` you can add them into List with

```
// declare a list first
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
list.add(x);
```

Comment: Ive already tried this. But that puts every line in a new Array. For example I print out the list it prints: [$25,913,000]
[$40,388,000]
[$48,995,000]
[$3,956,000]   But I want to have them in one Array: [$25,913,00, $40,388,00, $48,995,000]

Comment: if it's an array, you can get its first element, so finally you'll get this statement `list.add(x[0])`... hm, how can this be an array, if it's declared as `String x`?

Comment: No i want the String in an array

Comment: you can convert list to array `String[] array = new String[list.size()]; list.toArray(array);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element td = tds.first().siblingElements().first();

org.jsoup.nodes.Element td1 = tds.first().nextElementSibling();

org.jsoup.nodes.Element td2 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

org.jsoup.nodes.Element td3 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

org.jsoup.nodes.Element td4 = tds.first().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();

String x = td1.ownText();

System.out.println(x);
```

with

```
// create a list of Strings to store texts
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// to avoid calling first() many times assign the result to a variable
Element td = tds.first();

// instead of chaining next...next...next... you can iterate over all the siblings using iterator() and while loop
Iterator<Element> iter = td.siblingElements().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    // every sibling is assigned to a new variable
    Element sibling = iter.next();
    // sibling text is added to list
    list.add(sibling.ownText());
}

// display whole list
System.out.println(list);

// and if you really need an array you can transform it
String[] arrayWithTexts = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

you will be missing some imports but your IDE will help you with that and recommend fixes.

Comment: Thank u. If I print out the list it looks like: [Cash and Cash Equivalents, $25,913,000, $20,289,000, $20,484,000, $21,120,000]
[Short-Term Investments, $40,388,000, $53,892,000, $46,671,000, $20,481,000]… But I don´t want to print out the full list. How can I print out for example the second value from Cash and Cash Equivalents?

Comment: You should really read about arrays, loops, collections, iterators. To get the first value of an array use: arrayWithTexts[0], to get second: arrayWithTexts[1] ...
To get the first value of a list use: list.get(0), second: list.get(1) ...

Comment: Also if you liked the answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).